# Arba'a Veshishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred sixty-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible.*

*At some point between twenty-four hours and a few days from now, I will:*

- *Vote up all interesting, relevant answers.*
- *Accept what I consider the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

*Chodesh Tov!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Eretz Yisroel in the month of Tishrei there are 11 days of Yom Tov.

2 days Rosh HaShana, 1 day Yom Kippur, 8 days Succos.

11 days x 24 hours = **264** hours

Answer (score 1):

The first auto-da-fé of the Inquisition in Spain was in 1481. According to [Lee J. Levinger](http://books.google.com/books?id=o7xtAAAAMAAJ), "[t]he last execution [in Spain] on a charge of backsliding to Judaism was held in 1745, two hundred and sixty-four years later".

Answer (score 1):

In a leap year, *Yom Yerushalayim* is the 264th day in the year if *Heshvan* and *Kislev* are both *Haserim* (have 29 days):

*Tishrei* -30 days
*Heshvan*, *Kislev*, *Tevet* - 29 days each
*Shvat* - 30 days
*Adar A* - 29 days
*Adar B* - 30 days
*Nisan* - 30 days
*Iyar* - 28 days (*Yom Yerushalayim* is on the 28th day of *Iyar*)